# How to implement Panorama url image viewer on (react-native)ios

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, 360-panorama-viewer

I have only required PanoramaView on iOS and PanoramaView images comes from url.Now I am using react-native GVR. I have also implemented react-native-360 but not getting any solution.
Please help thanks in advance.

```
<PanoramaView 
style={{height :200, width:'100%'}}
imageUrl={image_url}
displayMode={'embedded'}
enableFullscreenButton
enableCardboardButton
enableTouchTracking
hidesTransitionView
enableInfoButton={false}
```

/>